# The farmer may or may not ferry something back to the other side of the river

Tags: alloy

[**Update**] I wrote up a description of the problem, how to model it using Alloy, and the solutions that the Alloy Analyzer found. My write-up is [here](http://xfront.com/Alloy/goat-cabbage-wolf.html). Comments welcome.

I created an Alloy model for the goat, cabbage, and wolf problem. See below.

If you are not familiar with the problem, here it is:

> A farmer wants to ferry across a river a goat, a cabbage, and a wolf,
>   but his boat only has room for him to take one at a time. If he leaves
>   the goat with the cabbage, the goat will eat it. If he leaves the goat
>   with the wolf, the goat will be eaten.

Initially, the farmer, goat, cabbage, and wolf are on side 1. The goal is for the farmer, goat, cabbage, and wolf to be on side 2.

The farmer makes a series of ferry's from side 1 to side 2 and back. When the farmer returns to side 1 from side 2 he may or may not bring something back. I think that my solution for that is not good. Here it is:

```
farmer in s.prev.side2 => {
    some i: s.prev.side2 - farmer { 
        ((s.side2 = s.prev.side2 - farmer - i) and (s.side1 = s.prev.side1 + farmer + i)) or 
        ((s.side2 = s.prev.side2 - farmer) and (s.side1 = s.prev.side1 + farmer))
    }
}
```

Read as: If the farmer was on side 2, then select one item from side 2 and either bring it over to side 1 or not. Ugh! That doesn't sound good. Is there a better way to implement the concept that the farmer may or may not bring something back to side 1?

Also, any other suggestions you might have for making my Alloy model simpler would be much appreciated.

Here is my Alloy model:

```
open util/ordering[State_of_each_side_of_river]

sig State_of_each_side_of_river {
    side1: set Item,
    side2: set Item
}

abstract sig Item {}
one sig farmer extends Item {}
one sig goat extends Item {}
one sig cabbage extends Item {}
one sig wolf extends Item {}

fact init {
    first.side1 = farmer + goat + cabbage + wolf
    first.side2 = none
}

fact final {
    some s: State_of_each_side_of_river |
        Moved_goat_cabbage_and_wolf_to_side2 [s]
}

fact constraints {
    no s: State_of_each_side_of_river { 
        (farmer in s.side1) and (goat + cabbage in s.side2) or
        (farmer in s.side2) and (goat + cabbage in s.side1) or
        (farmer in s.side1) and (goat + wolf in s.side2) or
        (farmer in s.side2) and (goat + wolf in s.side1)
    }
}

pred Moved_goat_cabbage_and_wolf_to_side2 (s: State_of_each_side_of_river) {
    s.side2 = farmer + goat + cabbage + wolf
    s.side1 = none
}

pred Ferrys_across_river {
    all s: State_of_each_side_of_river - first {
        Moved_goat_cabbage_and_wolf_to_side2 [s.prev] => {
            s.side1 = s.prev.side1
            s.side2 = s.prev.side2
        }
        else {
            farmer in s.prev.side1 => {
                some i: s.prev.side1 - farmer { 
                    s.side1 = s.prev.side1 - farmer - i
                    s.side2 = s.prev.side2 + farmer + i
                }
            }
            farmer in s.prev.side2 => {
                some i: s.prev.side2 - farmer { 
                    ((s.side2 = s.prev.side2 - farmer - i) and (s.side1 = s.prev.side1 + farmer + i)) or 
                    ((s.side2 = s.prev.side2 - farmer) and (s.side1 = s.prev.side1 + farmer))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

run Ferrys_across_river for 8
```

Comment: You might want to look at how the tutorial does it: http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/online/frame-RC-1.html